# No audio after rebooting Ubuntu 16.04 on dell vostro 5568

Tags: 16.04, drivers, sound, dell, alsa

It seems pretty random. Sometimes there is not even a detection of an audio device after reboot. 
Other times I can hear the drums at bootup but there is no sound while using the system. I am able to see the device in the settings menu however. But I cannot play a test sound either.

This is what I tried so far:

1. Force reload Alsa by  `sudo alsa force-reload reboot`.
2. Reinstalling Alsa and Pulsaudio by

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
   sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
   sudo alsa force-reload
   ```
3. `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"` shows:

   ```
   00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21)
       Subsystem: Dell Device 0786
       Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
       Memory at d1228000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
       Memory at d1200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
       Capabilities: <access denied>
       Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
       Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
   ```
4. `aplay -l` shows:

   ```
   **** Liste der Hardware-Geräte (PLAYBACK) ****
   Karte 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], Gerät 0: ALC3246 Analog [ALC3246 Analog]
     Sub-Geräte: 1/1
     Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
   Karte 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], Gerät 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
     Sub-Geräte: 1/1
     Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
   Karte 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], Gerät 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
     Sub-Geräte: 1/1
     Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
   Karte 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], Gerät 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
     Sub-Geräte: 1/1
     Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
   ```
5. `pactl list` short sinks shows:

   ```
   2   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
   ```

Comment: the random issue, I already know that but with my touchpad, I never find what was the problem on it

Comment: Does this occur on a dual-boot set-up with Windows? Some audio chipsets are known to not work in Linux if Windows is in hibernation.

Comment: No dualboot. Only Ubuntu 16.04. I always had problems with my headphones. Plugging in headphones led to system crash. But all of a sudden I can't hear any sound at all besides the drums at bootup.

Comment: Yesterday it even worked again for a short moment after several reboots. But it was pretty quiet then and I couldn't change the volume.

Answer (score 0):

You should open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
alsamixer
```

If you press the <kbd>F6</kbd> key you should see the sound card (If action keys are enables in your BIOS/EFI firmware you might have to press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>)

you will now see 3 options:

- <kbd>(default)</kbd>
- <kbd>0 HDA Intel PCH</kbd>
- <kbd>enter device name</kbd>

**[Note prom editor]:** *unclear what you're trying to accomplish here.  Please adapt this section* 
if I press esc key and then look into the system information 
I hold function the fn key and press f2 I can use the arrow keys to look at the /proc/asound/cards pressing return/enter I see two lines of information.

It could, if you write these two line into the text input with that device name in fn f6 select soundcard.
**[End note]**

Then exit alsamixer and type:

```
sudo apt-get update   
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Seems like there is nothing clicked off here. Tried to disable the auto-mute-mode but that didn't do anything.

Comment: Nope. This doesn't work for me. If I try to enter the two lines:  HDA-Intel - HDA Intel  HDA Intel PCH at 0xd1228000 irq 282 into the device name field     I akways get the error : File or folder not found.

Comment: **Plutesci** Could you please review my [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1047840/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... **;-)**

Comment: Fabby is that it?, I'm new here so not 100% sure on how to do that.